# Hover a div, affect another (CSS)

Tags: html, css, hover, selector

I managed to affect one `div` by hovering over a different `div` using the "+" selector, which I would like to avoid. I would like this to work even if the `.h div` and the `.t div` were inside different parents.

here is what i've got now: **http://jsfiddle.net/FranLegon/y06gg3vt/**

(it might look like a duplicated question, the answers did not help me solve this issue)
Although i would like to use CSS only, feel free to use javascript if it's the only way.

Comment: How would you like to "affect" other `div`s? What do you want to avoid the adjacent selector (`+`)? Why didn't you include code in your question?

Comment: @Mooseman you can see the code in the link. http://jsfiddle.net/FranLegon/y06gg3vt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS doesn't have parent or cousin selectors, so you'll need JavaScript for this:

```
var h= document.querySelector('.h');
var t= document.querySelectorAll('.ts .t');

h.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  for(var i = 0 ; i < t.length ; i++) {
    t[i].style.display= 'none';
  }
});

h.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  for(var i = 0 ; i < t.length ; i++) {
    t[i].style.display= 'inline-block';
  }
});
```

### Fiddle

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution using jquery using `.hover()` and `.toggleClass()`

http://jsfiddle.net/y06gg3vt/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.h').hover(function() {
        $('.ts .t').toggleClass('hide');
    });
});

.hide{
    display: none;
}
```